# Sync Microsoft 365 data to Netsuite

Tags: azure, integration, netsuite, suitescript, microsoft365

I would like to sync data from Microsoft 365 back to Netsuite. For example, you can create customers by entering information into Microsoft Excel. In my imagination, Netsuite would call API or something similar to access 365 data, and then we can extract data from that.

P/s: I do not know Microsoft Azure much. Recently, I successfully sign in to Netsuite using Azure SSO

Any comment would help a lot. Thanks

Comment: You need to use third party connector to integrate data from O365 to netsuite
have a look over this https://www.layer2solutions.com/solutions/general-data-integration/netsuite-codeless-data-integration-sychronization

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I need a more specific solution but thanks anyway.